# Set up While Loop to Sort Through String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, while-loop

I am trying to set up a while loop for the programs input and use hasNext to sort through the string array by delimiting the white space to get each line of input as a word. The program's purpose is to shuffle text in between first and last characters. Sorry for the beginner speak, I am just learning Java.

```
public class Scramble{

public static void main( String[] args){
        //read input 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] wordsList;

        while(in.hasNext()){
            //String[] wordsList;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sounds good. What's the issue or question?

Comment: Note: arrays have **fixed size**. You therefore are required to know how many values are going to be entered before they are entered

Comment: I suggest that you turn off your computer and get a piece of paper and pencil. Write **in words** the steps that you want to do. Use programming terms very sparingly. You should mostly concentrate on the steps you want to take, not the programming details.

Comment: You are just learning Java after have [similar questions over a year old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499733/adding-in-array-from-stdin)?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did this and am trying to break the program into pieces. Currently I want the program to be able to take in the input, store it into the string array `wordsList`, the break it into words based on whitespace..

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I dropped the class last year now i am re-taking it

Comment: @cricket_007 My question is how do I set up the while loop to go through the string array wordsList and break up the input into words

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not know the size of the array the instructor will use for input.

Comment: Have you reached out to your classmates or teachers. Despite your opinions of them, they probably don't want you to struggle. Us doing your assignments isn't going to help you pass exams and such when you're on your own.

Comment: Have you learned about `ArrayList`? If you need to collect all the inputs, that's what you need. Not an array. **Or** you must ask for a number first.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yea I understand and appreciate your comment, I am just looking for someone to guide me in the right direction.. I have been staring at this code for a few hours. I think ArrayList is a better data structure for this case.

Comment: Take the first step, reading a line of input. Figure out how to do this and print it back to the screen.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice should I setup a `system.println(...)` statement to prompt the user for input in order to test this.. for the final version of the program it will not require any prompt for user to enter data

Comment: Since it is not required in the final version, I would skip it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have input on one line, you can split it

```
String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Otherwise, you have a loop, and you need a data structure without a fixed size.

Like a list

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    words.add(scanner.nextLine());
```

Comment: Great thank you for the helpful explanation.. I really appreciate it man!

Comment: Would I add the regex to breakup by whitespace within the while loop?

Comment: As far as the input goes, I am pretty sure the instructor will test it by dumping a lines of text, there won't be a user prompt to enter any data.

Comment: My objective is to get the program just to break up the input into words, then eventually scramble them once i get there

Comment: You're welcome to split, substring, or whatever on the string during the loop. I don't really know your expected output, but feel free to create a new post with that clearly defined and your attempts at the solution

Comment: Will do thanks for the help cricket.. we didn't have the smoothest start